# How to change Firefox language?

Tags: firefox, locale

I have a Scientific Linux on my notebook (installed with German language).

I installed Firefox with a simple "yum install firefox".

But I need Firefox with Hungarian language.

How can I configure Firefox to use Hungarian language? (menus, etc. )

ps.: no, the tools->contents->change language didn't helped in Firefox.

Comment: The tools->contents->change language option is for requesting pages in specific languages. Although some sites insist in using flag buttons and such, HTTP has built-in support for a browser to say "hand me english or, if not possible, french, or then portuguese". It has nothing to do with the Firefox UI language.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, you have to find and `.xpi` file for the requested language. As far as I know there is no place which concentrates all languages. Then perform following steps:

1. In the addressbar paste `about:config`. Hit Enter. A list of different preferences will appear.
2. Paste `general.useragent.locale` to the search tab. Only one preference will appear.
3. Double click on the preference and enter a code of your language (*for example **de-DE** or **en-US***)
4. Restart FF

Comment: Since a while ago, I even though Mozilla has given up in providing separate language packs, instead supplying localized packages (that only had en-US *and* another language). But fortunately, there are still XPIs out there, see http://kb.mozillazine.org/Language_packs. Also, if Firefox does it the right way™, then running firefox with `LC_ALL` set to the desired locale (e.g. `LC_ALL=pt_PT.utf8 firefox` for european portuguese) should work too.